# About particular extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $E/K$ be an extension field. If $A\subseteq E$ and $u\in K(A)$, prove that there are $a_1,\dots,a_n\in A$ such that $u\in K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

I thought to use the fact that $K(A)$ is a $K(u)$-vector space, but I didn't manage to progress much. Please let me know if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: This will be obvious if you write down the definition of $K(A)$.

Comment: $K(A)$ is the intermediate field $F$ generated by $K\cup A$. I still don't see how the result follows.

Comment: But just what *is* the field generated by (blah)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $L=$ {$x$ | $x$ can be described with rational expression with $k_1,..,k_n∈K$ and $a_1,..,a_m∈A$}

You can verify that:
・$L$ forms a field.
・Field containing $K(A)$ must contain $L$

So $L = K(A)$ and its every element can be described with rational expression with $k_1,..,k_n∈K$ and $a_1,..,a_m∈A$.